# If a Borelian set has positive measure, does it contain a non empty open set  (minus a measure null set)?

Tags: measure-theory

Let A be a borelian set with postivie measure. I was asking myself if it is possible to find an open set $B\subseteq A$ such that $B$ is an open set minus a set of null measure...

Comment: do you mean:"... such that $B$ is $A$ minus a set of null measure?

Comment: No, I mean that there exists an open set B' and a set N of null measure such that B=B'\N

Comment: Ok.. So $B$ is only open in the subspace topology of $A$, but not in the entire measure space?

Comment: I mean that $B$ is equal almost everywhere to an open set... It can also be not open in $A$ topology, (if you add a point to $B$ the condition remains the same, and B can fail to be an open set in A topology)

Comment: Ok. Then remove the condition that $B$ *IS* open.

Comment: I guess the answer given by Petya is in most books on measure theory, so have you done your homework (as asked in the faq)?

Comment: I've given real analysis exam 6 years ago, and I didn't remember of cantor sets of positive measure. Furthermore I thought that some general question, even if you can find in books (you can find everything in books!), could be interesting also for others! Sorry if I have annoyed you. "have done your homework"...... I have no homework to do.

Comment: Nicolò, I think it is a perfectly fine question. There are numerous concepts of largeness (having full measure, having positive measure, being nonmeager, being comeager, etc. etc.) and I find it to be some interesting mathematics to see how they all relate. 

Comment: Thank you Joel, I find them interesting too, even though  others see this things only as "homework" stuff

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Cantor set of positive measure is nowhere dense set. So it is an example.

Comment: Isn't the Cantor set of null measure?

Comment: I mean the well-known construction (similar to the construction of Cantor set), when one delete middle intervals smaller then $1/3^n$. The resulting set has positive measure and homeomorphic to the standard Cantor set of measure zero.

Comment: ok, thanks! In wikipedia i've found such sets under the name of "cantor-smith-volterra sets"

Comment: I think it's also called a fat Cantor set?

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question, as I see it.  Let $A$ be this fat Cantor set.  We know it is nowhere dense, so contains no open set.  But we actually want to know that $A \cup E$ contains no open set, where $E$ is any null set.  Does this follow?  Of course $A \cup E$ may no longer be nowhere dense.

Comment: Nate, if A union E contained an interval, then it must be that A is dense on that interval, for otherwise there would be a tiny subinterval inside E, preventing it from having measure 0.

Comment: Nate, a difference between an interval and a null measure set is dense in the interval. The intersection of a fat Cantor set with any interval is nowhere dense and hence is not dense in the interval.